# the static member variable assignment

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class base
{
    static base* mybase;
};
base::mybase = NULL;
char* str = "hello world";
int main()
{
    std::cout<<"hello world"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

why the the line of  code"base::mybase = NULL"  compiler error!

Comment: Whenever you post questions involving errors, please post the complete error message you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the type too. The type of `mybase` is `base*`:

```
base* base::mybase = NULL;
```

This defines a `base*` that is a member of `base` and is called `mybase` and initializes it to `NULL`.

Comment: I know the answer,but I don't konw why?

Comment: @user1965184 Because it's a variable definition - it has to begin with a type. Just the same way `int x = 5;` does.

Answer (score 2):

You should also give the type of the variable in the line:

```
base* base::mybase = NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

> why the the line of code `base::mybase = NULL` compiler error!

Because it isn't a valid declaration. It would be a valid assignment expression (in a context that has access to private members of class base), but you can't have expression statements at namespace scope.

To provide the definition of the static member, use

```
base* base::mybase = NULL;
```